# Merge 2 Arrays Interchanging Index PHP

Tags: php, arrays, merge

Not sure if I described it properly in the title, but I'm looking to merge 2 arrays in php, although I don't want the new array to have the first array first and then the second array at the end, instead I want it to have the first item of the first array, first item of the second array, 2nd item of the first array, etc

so essentially

```
Array 1
     A - 1
     A - 2
     A - 3

Array 2
     B - 1
     B - 2
     B - 3
```

and after merging the two, the resulting array will be

```
Array Merged
     A - 1
     B - 1
     A - 2
     B - 2
     A - 3
     B - 3
```

In that order, can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge and sort them, while keeping the keys

```
$array1 = array(/* values here */);
$array2 = array(/* values here */);

$mergedArray = array_merge($array1, $array2);
ksort($mergedArray); // this also keeps the keys
```

**Note:**

Your arrays can't work, since you can't have 2 entries with the same keys :)

Basically `$array2 = array('B' => 1, 'B' => 2, 'B' => 3);` will result in the following array:

```
Array
(
    [B] => 3
)
```

Comment: `ksort()` returns a bool. How will this make the merged array have alternating keys?

Comment: `ksort()` modifies the array it's working with, you don't need to asign a value, just continue using the array.